# Email Address is not Contained in Response, Even the Token has "email" Permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

If someone registers himself on my app I should be able to use their email. But only name and id are returned from Facebook in the following request:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me&version=v2.4

I checked the scope of my token for my app with
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
which looks okay to me:

```
Scopes: email, public_profile
```

How to obtain the email in the response?

It does not even work if I obtain the token via the "Get Token" function in the Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

For v2.4 it works only if you add the needed files to the graph request:

```
/me?fields=name,email
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cemail&version=v2.4

While v2.3 should receive any fields.